# Pointer to picturebox

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, c++-cli

I am trying to learn C++ using Visual Studio 2005.  I have created a form that contains many PictureBoxes and I would like to be able to refer them via an array.  Before creating an array, I'm trying to create a single pointer variable to see how it works.

Here is what I've tried:

```
System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox *p = &animation::Form1::Boule1;
```

But it gives me error 2440 saying that it can't convert.  I have also tried ^ instead of * but it doesn't work.

How should I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I'ts not relevant, but why 2005? Maybe Boule1 is already a pointer, so do this: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox *p = animation::Form1::Boule1;

Comment: Inside of the form just do `PictureBox^ p = this->Boule1;`. What you're doing is more akin to getting an pointer-to-data-member, which is not what you want. Also, what you're using is **not** C++, but C++/CLI – entirely different languages. If you want to learn C++, ditch the "CLR" project variants and use the "Win32" ones instead.

Comment: @user1914198 : Use the name of your `Form1` object and make sure `Boule1` is public – if you don't _have_ a `Form1` object then you can't very well access data members of `Form1`. ;-]

Comment: Placing PictureBox^ p = this->Boule1; inside the form works, but if I'm elsewhere, I can't use the this keyword, what should I use instead?  What if I'm in main()?

Comment: If you're in `main` then you need a `Form1` object; once you have that object, use its name instead of `this`... But like I said, if your goal is to learn C++, you're very much on the wrong track, as you're using C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

animation::Form1::Boule1 might already be a pointer.  In that case, try just doing:

```
System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox *p = animation::Form1::Boule1
```

Otherwise, can we see the whole error message so we know what it's trying to convert?